# numpy stack to 2d array, select by index from another stack

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have two sets of classifications (`Lc1` and `Lc2`) and two sets of probabilities (`Lp1` and `Lp2`).  `Lp1` is the set of probabilities that describes the classification likelihood in `Lc1`. I want to combine the information in `Lc1` and `Lc2` using the classifications that are the most probable into `class_result`.

```
import numpy as np

#example data
Lp1 = np.ones((2,2))*0.5
Lc2 = np.ones((2,2))

Lc1 = np.ones((2,2))
Lp2 = np.ones((2,2))*0.5

#Change some values for the example
Lp1[1,1] =0.95
Lc1[1,1] = 0

Lc2[0,1]=3
Lp2[0,1]=.95

p_stack = np.stack((Lp1,Lp2))
c_stack = np.stack((Lc1,Lc2))

index = np.argmax(p_stack, axis=2)

class_result = np.take(c_stack, index)
```

My initial approach is to create a `np.stack` for the sets of classifications and probabilities and use `np.argmax` to find the axis index where the maximum value occurs in `p_stack`.  The docs for [np.take](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) seem to describe the operation I need to do, but I don't understand why it returns an array with ones.  Is there a way to reduce the dimensionality of a `np.stack` by specifying the axis of the value I want to select?

My desired result is:

```
class_result = np.array([[1,3],[1,0]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `ìndex` refers to the first dimension, and you need to create ascending indices for the other dimensions.

If you write them manually it looks like

```
dim_1 = np.array([[0, 0],
                  [1, 1]])


dim_2 = np.array([[0, 1],
                  [0, 1]])

print(c_stack[index, dim_1, dim_2])
```

You can create them automatically using `np.arange`, `np.vstack`, `np.hstack` and `np.tile`, `np.column_stack`. There are several ways to do this.

E.g.

```
x = np.arange(5)

a = np.tile(x, (5, 1))
b = np.column_stack(tuple(a))
print(a)
print(b)
```

This technique in Numpy is called ["Integer array indexing"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing).

Comment: This link you provided is very helpful.

Comment: I know, I visit it on a daily basis because I forget how it works all the time :)