# Advanced integer indexing with l x m x n broadcast shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Earlier today I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967890/numpy-stack-to-2d-array-select-by-index-from-another-stack/51968369#51968369) about integer array indexing and I am having trouble taking the answer and applying it to the problem that inspired the question.

In a nutshell, `p_stack1` and `c_stack1` contain arrays that are derived from an image processing algorithm I am working on.  `p_stack1` contains probability data and `c_stack1` contain integer classifications.  I need to find the classification that has the highest probability for every pixel in the image with dimensions 768 x 1024.  From the docs for [integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing), it provides a way to subset data from higher dimensional arrays using their integer indexes.

The solution of my original question works for a simplified example of n x n x n shaped arrays, but does not seem to work on l x m x n shaped arrays.

```
#dummy data
p_stack1 = np.reshape(np.random.uniform(0,1,2359296),(3,768,1024))
c_stack1 = np.reshape(np.random.randint(0,4,2359296),(3,768,1024))

#find where max value occurs on axis 0
ind_new=p_stack1.argmax(axis=0)

#Create assending indicies
nx, ny = 768,1024
xx = np.arange(ny)
aa= np.tile(xx,(ny,1))
bb = np.column_stack(tuple(aa))[:nx,:]
aa= np.tile(xx,(ny,1))[:nx,:]

#perform the integer array indexing
print(c_stack1[ind_new, aa,bb])
```

The last print statement returns the error:

```
IndexError: index 768 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 768
```

I checked the shapes of `aa` and `bb` and both are `(768, 1024)`

What I am I missing?

Comment: Can you explain in prose what you're trying to accomplish? I feel like there's a much simpler way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you got your dimensions mixed up:

```
c_stack1.shape   # (3, 768, 1024)
aa.max()         # 1023
bb.max()         # 767
```

So, when you run

```
c_stack1[ind_new, aa, bb]
```

you will be trying to index `axis=1` with higher values than available, hence the error

Either turn around `aa` and `bb`, or else `c_stack1[ind_new, bb, aa]` will also do the trick

Comment: aren't you pointing out the fact that numpy does 0-based indexing? `aa` and `bb` are arrays containing ascending indices for each dimension. In the case of `aa`, 1023 is the 1024th element.

Comment: I was pretty sure that was the cause, initially. But the 0-based indexing has nothing to do with your error in this case, except that the first row that exceeds the bounds of axis 1 (`index 768 is out of bounds for axis 1`) is row 768, hence the error message. The point of your problem, however, is that you are trying to index with indices above 1000, when there are actually only 767 in that particular dimension (axis 1)

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation.  My blood sugar must be low.  Makes perfect sense after lunch!